# Is there any way to check if a maven dependency exists in the remote repository

Tags: gradle

I'm working on a Gradle project, that reads a list of dependencies from a config file and add them to the Gradle build file.
It must first download the dependency in zip format from a private JFrog repository, if a dependency does not exist in that repo, it will be downloaded from public repositories.
The problem is if a dependency does not exist in our private repo, the build will be failed.

```
   file("${rootDir}/modules/assembly/src/main/resources/cfg.properties").withReader {
        Properties configs = new Properties()
        configs.load(it)
        project.ext.configs = configs
    }

    project.ext.configs.findAll { it.key.contains('disabled') && it.value == 'false' }.each { entry ->
        // read the configuration of a dependency from config file
        // if it exist in the private repo, add dependency in zip type
        project.dependencies.add("driver", "${configs[keyGroup]}:${configs[keyName]}:${configs[keyVersion]}@zip")
        // else add dependency in jar type
        project.dependencies.add("driver", "${configs[keyGroup]}:${configs[keyName]}:${configs[keyVersion]}@jar")
        }
    }
```

So I want to know if there is any way to check if a dependency is in the private repo, if it's not in there, it will not be added to the Gradle build file in zip format but in jar format.
Thanks.